# set Key column info of binded grid view directly with database to perform CRUD? updation issue

Tags: c#, datagridview, ado.net, dataset, dataadapter

I have created data set in designer and then i use it to bind with grid-view control in win-forms this is datagridview  my binding is successful and i also perform the insertion successfully but issue is in Updation and deletion
HERE is my code to load and bind data

```
     public void load() {
         dataGridView1.DataSource = null;          
        ds = new DataSet1();
        table = ds.Tables[ds.Customer.TableName];
        ad = new DataSet1TableAdapters.CustomerTableAdapter();
        ad.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
        ad.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = true;
        DataColumn[] PK_Column = new DataColumn[1];
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("cmpid", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        PK_Column[0] = dc;
        dc.AutoIncrement = false;
        ad.GetData(); 
        ad.Adapter.Fill(ds.Customer);
       // ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = PK_Column;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Customer;
    }
```

but on cell value change event i want it to update database , but it won't work i am checking in debugging the value in dataset that is binded is also changed but saving are not saved in db whyprivate void

```
 private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender,  DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommandBuilder cb;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        table = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).GetChanges();
        if (ds != null)
        {
            cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(ad.Adapter);
            ad.Adapter.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand(true);
            ad.Adapter.Update(dt);
        }

   }
```

why insertion is successful here but not updation , deletion

REASON :

> Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against
>   a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

**set Key column info in load function();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

(`GetChanges()` method works with row events, so I used **datagrid**'s `RowValidated` event.)

```
 private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
            SqlCommandBuilder cb;
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).GetChanges();
            if (ds != null)
            {
                cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adp);
                adp.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand(true);
                adp.Update(dt);
            }

}
```

**Update 1;**

Another way to do this without any primary key,

```
string newValue = "";
SqlCommand cmd;
string oldValue = "";

private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
      oldValue = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); // store old value to add where 
}
```

In cell value changed, we will update db with a dynamic way that I thought (If better or any suggestions please inform me.)

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=localdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123");
        if (c.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            c.Open();
        }
        string command = "";
        string columns = "";
        string columnName = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name; // get column name of edited cell
        if (dataGridView1.Columns.Count != 1) // If there is only one column we dont have any where comparison, so we need oldValue of cell (we took value at cellbeginedit event)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i != e.ColumnIndex)
                {
                    columns += dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name + " = '" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString() + "' "; // compare statement according to other cells (assume that we don't have PK)
                }
                if ((i != dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1) && (i != e.ColumnIndex))
                {
                    columns += " and ";

                }
            }
            command = "Update "+ ds.Customer.TableName +" set " + columnName + "=@newValue where " + columns;
        }
        else
        {
            command = "Update  " + ds.Customer.TableName + "  set  " + columnName + "=@newValue where ColumName=" + "'" + oldValue + "'";
        }
        newValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString(); //our new parameter.
        cmd = new SqlCommand(command, c);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newValue", newValue);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        c.Close();

}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: `{"Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information."}`

Comment: CHECK UPDATED QUESTION

Comment: @zulqarnainkhalil you don't have PK (unique) column in your table, thats why you are getting that error. Update operation needs a unique column to make operation.

Comment: yeah but if i make updation by logically giving coloumnb name that i use as primary key...

Comment: suppose if user have 3 logical pk like companyID , branchID , emplyeeID , that are use for operations then

Comment: @zulqarnainkhalil tried to produce another solution, because `getChanges()` not work without PK. Hope helps this one. Check updated answer.

Comment: BUT I AM NOT USING CONNECTION STRING THERE

Comment: @zulqarnainkhalil you have to modify the code, ı can't write the exact code. Trying to show a way to you.